# Security risks of setting trustworthy = on in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2012, sqlclr, full-trust

I get the following errors in my development database:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SpCreateTable": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading
```

Is the correct solution to set trustworthy = on? What are security concerns with this?

Answer (score 11):

The `TRUSTWORTHY` property of a database (when set to `ON`) essentially declares to SQL Server that code contained within that database, and executing in an impersonated context, should be allowed to reach outside of that database while maintaining that impersonated security context. It also allows for *all* SQLCLR Assemblies in that Database to be set to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` and `UNSAFE`, whether or not that code reaches outside of the server (outside meaning: network access, file system access, registry access, environment access, etc).

It is a rather generic means of allowing for this as it covers all code within the database. Using Certificates and/or Asymmetric Keys to sign modules--procs and/or assemblies--allow for more granular control over what code has what permissions.

Setting a Database to `TRUSTWORTHY` also allows any process starting in this Database to reach up to the Server-level and/or across to other Databases. Normally a process is confined / quarantined to the Database where it started. If the Database is owned by the "sa" Login, then any process initiated in that Database and running as "dbo" will effectively have "sa" privileges (yikes!).

Rather than trying to describe here, in the amount of detail required to fully communicate the specifics about impersonation, extending said impersonation, signing modules, etc, I recommend perusing the following resources on this topic:

- [PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)
- [Guidelines for using the TRUSTWORTHY database setting in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183687)
- [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188304(v=sql.105))
  This is a very informative document that covers most aspects of this topic, and is also referenced in the linked page above.
- [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 4: Security (EXTERNAL and UNSAFE Assemblies)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sqlclr-level-4-security-external-and-unsafe-assemblies)
  This is an article I wrote as part of a series on SQLCLR that has examples which illustrate the differences between the TRUSTWORTHY method and the Signed Assembly-based Login method; Free registration is required.

You should avoid setting your database to `TRUSTWORTHY` as much as possible. If you really must have multithreading / async calls AND if you have the source code and are compiling the assembly, then I cannot think of a reason to use the `SET TRUSTWORTHY ON` option. Instead, you should sign the assembly *with a password* and use the following commands to set up the preferred method of allowing `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` and `UNSAFE` assemblies:

```
USE [master];
  CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [ClrPermissionsKey]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\path\to\my\assembly.dll';

CREATE LOGIN [ClrPermissionsLogin]
  FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [ClrPermissionsKey];

GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [ClrPermissionsLogin];
```

Once that is in place, you can go to the database where your assembly has been loaded and run:

```
ALTER ASSEMBLY [MyAssembly] WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

Or you could have included `WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` at the end of the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` command.

Comment: They actually are signed with an asymmetric key and set to unsafe but still get that error. not sure why

Comment: +1 for offering a valid workaround, but you haven't really addressed the real question (specific and explicit risks about TRUSTWORTHY in general).

Comment: @chris Are you sure that the assembly is set to UNSAFE? The error you posted is what you get when the assembly is not set to unsafe. Or, when it was set to UNSAFE but then the Login was removed or at least had the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission removed. If any of that is not the case, then what framework methods are you calling in your proc method?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Thanks. And I have now updated the answer to provide some details and links to more info regarding implications of TRUSTWORTHY.

Comment: Solomon, and Aaron how do you register System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll on SQL Server 2016 without using TRUSTWORTHY? I have tried, and tried but cannot seem to make it work with an ASYMMETRIC key.

Comment: @SpaceGhost440 I have an answer here somewhere that shows how to do that. Lemme find it and I will paste a link for it here. Of course, this assumes that `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` is a pure-MSIL assembly. If not, then there is no way to load it no matter what.

Comment: @SpaceGhost440 I answered [your question on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/230995/30859) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `TRUSTWORTHY ON` opens a potential security breach by allowing any code to reach external resources under database impersonation context. It's perfectly fine to allow your DB to access protected network shares using a code you're in control of, however it might be not that wise to allow the same for any code.

Setting this flag just opens a door for anyone gained dbo permissions for a particular DB as you might register any assembly and it'll have DB impersonation context at its discretion.