# Issue creating asymmetric key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run the code below but continuously get the error "The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it."

I have tried changing file permissions, running as an administrator (this is on a local database), restarting the SQL service and my computer but nothing is fixing it.

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [DatabaseName_UserDefinedFunctions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\Users\username\Source\Project\Database\DatabaseProject\bin\Output\ProjectName.Database.SiteDb.dll';
```

Comment: Check this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018365/is-it-possible-to-create-an-asymmetric-key-for-a-net-framework-assembly-in-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639213/how-to-grant-the-database-owner-dbo-the-external-access-assembly-permission